# BrainTree: get all customer's payment methods

Tags: braintree

There is a way to get a list of all cards:

```
gateway.creditCard.expiringBetween(year1900, year2100, function (err, result) {...})
```

and then call `paymentMethod.find` for each individual card.  But I would like to get all payment methods associated with a customer, in one call, is this possible?

Comment: I work at Braintree. Generally, you shouldn't need to get all payment methods in the Braintree vault (is that what you're trying to do?). What's your use case?

Comment: No, I was trying to get all the payment methods for specific customer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, you can always [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

A customer is serialized with all of its payment methods.

So, [get the customer](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+node/sdk/server/customer-management/search#single-customer) and then [get the credit cards and paypal accounts from it](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+node/reference/objects/customer#associations):

```
gateway.customer.find("theCustomerId", function(err, customer) {
    var payment_methods = customer.creditCards.concat(customer.paypalAccounts);
});
```

Comment: @RobFox Please don't make edits that don't substantially improve an answer. I understand you just got edit privileges and are excited to use them, but the same rules apply as before you got them -- only make significant edits.

Comment: hey can you do this in a React frontend app?  Or is this just for the backend?

Comment: @rom I no longer work at Braintree but AFAIK you need to do this from the backend; if you want to avoid having to do that you might be able to use the drop-in UI and not need to fetch payment methods yourself. https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/start/drop-in

Answer (score 2):

I figured that. `gateway.customer.find` returns an object with property `creditCards`, just wasn't obvious from the documentation.